# orientdb ETL using jdbc example not accepted

Tags: json, jdbc, orientdb

yesterday I start using orientdb, and i found plenty of ETL examples using jdbc, but something is missing with me, I guess, I cannot run the script, I tried by console and via browser and nothing.

I have the JSON code for ETL:

```
{
  "config": {"log": "debug"},
  "extractor" : { "jdbc": { "driver": "PostgreSQL (org.postgresql.Driver)",
                            "url": "jdbc:postgresql://link_to_my_relational_database",
                            "userName": "myuser",
                            "userPassword": "mypassword",
                            "query": "select * from Author" 
                          }
                },
  "transformers" : [{ "vertex": { "class": "Author"} }],
  "loader" : {"orientdb": { "dbURL": "hlocal:/temp/databases/TFCShare",
                            "dbAutoCreate": true
                          }
              }
}
```

when i try to run this ELT via web i have the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: text cannot be null` 
what could be the problem? everybody else seems to have it right and their code look the same as mine.

Comment: How are you running this?

Comment: via console i tried " script json and then the script end"...i have the message json is not a supported language, via web browser i just paste the script in the bar and i have the java exception

Comment: have you tried with the `oetl.sh` (or `oetl.bat`) script? you'll find them in the orient bin directory

Comment: Usage: `./oetl.sh jsonfile.json`

Comment: oh my god, thank you...that was it. use oetl.sh to run the json script